# Can i execute an on-demand web job from a scheduled webjob?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I need to execute a long running webjob on certain schedules or on-demand with some parameters that need to be passed. I had it in a way where the scheduled webjob would put a message on the queue with the parameters and a queue message triggered job would take over - OR - some user interaction would put the same message on the queue with the parameters and the triggered job would take over. However for some reason the triggered function never-finishes - and right now i cannot see any exceptions being displayed in the dashboard outputs (see [Time limit on Azure Webjobs triggered by Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35034114/time-limit-on-azure-webjobs-triggered-by-queue))

I m looking into whether I can execute my triggered webjob as an On-demand webjob and pass the parameters to it? Is there anyway to call an on-demand web job from a scheduled web job and pass it some command line parameters?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

QueueTriggered WebJob functions work very well when configured properly. Please see my answer on the other question which points to [documentation resources](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/) on how to set your WebJobs SDK Continuous host up properly.

Queue messaging is the correct pattern for you to be using for this scenario. It allows you to pass arbitrary data along to your job, and will also allow you to scale out to multiple instances as needed when your load increases.

You can use the **WebJobs Dashboard** to invoke your job function directly (see "Run Function" button below) - you can specify the queue message input directly in the Dashboard as a string. This allows you to **invoke the function directly** as needed with whatever inputs you want, in addition to allowing the function to continue to respond to qeueue messages actually added to the queue.

[image]